# run time error while running android appp on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I had make some button in the program when I run the project. Logcat appears and shows run time errors like this:

```
12-11 02:10:47.838: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.deadlyweed.bhanuj.startingpoint.onCreate(startingpoint.java:23)
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Too generic error. Maybe something related to null pointers...

Be sure not being calling methods of objects not instantiated, working with the result of a function assuming that it will never be null...

Anyway, you should give more details.

What do you have in your *onCreate()* method?

Comment: counter=0;
        add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.badd);
        add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bsub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvdisplay);                                                           
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()                                                i had used 2 buttons for adding and subtracting    named add and sub then i had used onclick function to increment/dercremnt the counter and to display the result

Comment: You are assigning the two buttons to the "add" variable (seems to be an effect of copy+paste). I assume the second button should be assigned to something like "sub". If you access "sub", you will have the null pointer error.

Comment: thnnx a lot bddy.. what a rubbish  mistake i had done. nd i was thinkin like i can't do these silly mistakes.. thxxx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the app, that worked when I had a nullpointer in onCreate out of the blue